# Error parentkey and childkey are identical in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, wpf, report, stimulsoft

I want to created a master-detail Report.

I have two classes `PayStub` & `Payments` that payments have foreignkey of `PayStubId`.

```
public class PayStub
{
 public int PayStubId { get; set; }
 public int Code { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Payment
{
 [ForeignKey("PayStub ")]
 public int PayStubId { get; set; }
 public  PayStub PayStub { get; set; }
 public int Amount{ get; set; }
 public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

I've tried two ways:

1. Business object.Insert parent business object & child business object and in wpf.

   report.RegBusinessObject("PayStub", payList);
   report.RegBusinessObject("Payments", paymentList);

this show master and don't show detail.

2. DataTable.Insert two DataTable and a relation for this.

in wpf:

```
report.RegData("PayStub", payList);
report.RegData("Payments", paymentList);
```

I get error `parentkey and childkey are identical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change models like this.

```
public class PayStub
{
public int PayStubId { get; set; }
public int Code { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Payment> Payments{ get; set; }
}
public class Payment
```

{
   [ForeignKey("PayStub ")]
   public int PayStubId { get; set; }
   public  PayStub PayStub { get; set; }
   public int Amount{ get; set; }
   public string Description{ get; set; }
   }

and set payments value in PsyStubList.

and set `BusinessObject` only for PayStub

```
report.RegBusinessObject("PayStub", payList);
```